# Correctly skipping empty fields with sqlldr

Tags: import, format, sql-loader

I need to upload a tab-separated file into an existing Oracle table. Some of the records have empty fields (not whole columns as has been answered before) in the middle, and I can't get sqlldr to correctly load the fields following the empty one for the record. Consider the example file:

```
ID->   col1-> col2-> col3
rec1-> 1.28-> 2.56-> 5.12
rec2-> 1.28-> -> 
rec3->     ->     -> 5.12
```

and the following control file upload.ctl:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1) 
load data  infile 'file.tab'
replace into table TARGET_TABLE
fields terminated by "\t" optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (ID char terminated by "\t",
     col1 terminated by "\t",
     col2 terminated by "\t",
     col3 terminated by "\t")
```

will result in the following upload:

```
+------+------+------+------+
|ID    |col1  |col2  |col3  |
+------+------+------+------+
|rec1  |1.28  |2.56  |5.12  |
|rec2  |1.28  |(null)|(null)|
|rec3  |5.12  |(null)|(null)|
```

The empty fields in the file to upload are filled in with the correct number of tab character, but sqlldr seems to recognise consecutive tabs as one. How can I prevent that?
Thanks for checking my newbie question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not seeing the TAB as a separator.  Change the fields terminated line to:

```
fields terminated by X'09' optionally enclosed by '"'
```

and remove the "terminated by "\t"" from each column entry as its unneeded there.